# Equivalent proof strategies

Tags: proof-writing

I am trying to prove that 4 statements, say A, B , C , and D are all equivalent. Would this string of implications get me to my desired results.

I can prove that $A \iff B$, $A \implies C$ , $C \implies D$, and $D \implies A$.

Am I missing an implication to complete the chain?

Comment: No, your implications are sufficient.

Comment: You can do it with four implications instead of five: $A\implies B$, $B\implies C$, $C\implies D$ and $D\implies A$.

Comment: In theory, yes but the chain that i described was a more natural way to prove the statements at hand.